# CSS style as color attribute on font tags

Tags: html, rgb

```
<html>
    <body>
      <font color="#FF0000">Red</font>
      <BR>
      <font color=green>Green</font>
      <BR>
      <font color= rgb(255,255,0)>Gold</font>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

From the code above I am trying to use different ways to change the font color. The first 2 ways work perfectly (in hex and the actual name); but the third one in RGB format is not displayed correct. What is the error in there?

Comment: Using `font` tags. Those values only all work as CSS properties. You shouldn't be using font anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`style="color:rgb(255,255,0)"`. The font tag is deprecated and inline style should also be avoided. Don't forget your double quotes on attribute names: `attr="value"` not `attr=value`

This would be best done in CSS using a target class:

```
<p class="my-class">Some text</p>
```

In your css file:

```
.my-class {
  color: rgb(255,255,0);
}
```

The 
 tag is also not to be used for layout. It should only be used for new-lines in text. Instead, use `display: block` on the elements that should be on a new line.

Here's a complete sample: (note that `<p>` tags have `display: block` by default)

```
<p class="red-text">Red</p>
<p class="green-text">Green</p>
<p class="gold-text">Gold</p>
```

CSS:

```
.red-text {
  color: #FF0000; 
}

.green-text {
  color: green; 
}

.gold-text {
  color: rgb(255,255,0);
}
```

[**Live demo (click).**](http://jsbin.com/ohupItA/1/edit)

Comment: I know it is obsolete, but my assignment wants it specifically that way :/ what is the correct formatting for the RGB? Thanks anyways!

Comment: @user3217651 there is no correct formatting. `rgb` won't work there. Whoever assigned you this is dead wrong for suggesting `font` and should not be teaching anyone. I would let them know I said so.

Comment: @user3217651 anyway, the very first thing that I showed you is the solution no matter what tag you use. `<font style="color:rgb(255,255,0)">Gold</font>`

Comment: oh so there is literally no way to do it like that >.> thanks for the info. Although I think he knew what was going on (he started talking and stopped himself for a sec) but didn't want to tell any of us so that we had to figure it out ._.

Comment: @user3217651 the font tag though...it's awful.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 <style>
   .red{
       color: #FF0000;
  }
</style>
```

HTML Tag:

```
 <div class="red" >Red</div>
```

Comment: @m59, Yeah, You right !. I was answered, whilst you answered as `style="color:rgb(255,255,0)"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>webpage name</title>
</head>
<body>
<font color="#FF0000">Red</font> (it's look right).
<BR>
<font color=green>Green</font>(wrong).
<BR>
<font color= rgb(255,255,0)>Gold</font>(wrong).
</body>
</html>
```

modified

```
<html>
<head>
<title>webpage name</title>
</head>
<body>
<font color="#FF0000">Red</font>
<BR>
<font color="green">Green</font>
<BR>
<font color="rgb(255,255,0)">Gold</font>
</body>
</html>
```